# Como recebo um JSON e armazeno em uma lista?

Tags: json, objective-c, mobile, xcode

Queria receber um JSON que contenha varias mensagens e armazena-lo em uma lista que contenha um conteúdo do JSON por posição

O formato do JSON seria este:

```
[{"id":"42","data":"02\/12\/2015 12:01:21","texto":"blablabla","nome":null},
 {"id":"48","data":"02\/12\/2015 12:02:21","texto":"kkkkkkk","nome":fulano},
 {"id":"29","data":"03\/12\/2015 12:02:21","texto":"hi ha ho","nome":jhonn}]
```

No xCode, estou trabalhando com Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa de converter essa *string* para um `NSData`:

```
NSData *data = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

E então, para um `NSArray`, que é uma lista de `NSDictionary`:

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: nil error: &error];
```